# Who are the 20th century painters on this t-shirt?

Tags: 20th-century, cultural-history, art

I bought this t-shirt for a friend who is really into arts, but actually I don't know all the painters that are pictured on this shirt.
Clock-wise, I recognize:

1. René Magritte
2. Edvard Munch
3. Salvador Dalí
4. Wassily Kandinsky ?
5. Jackson Pollock
6. ?
7. Piet Mondrian
8. Gustav Klimt
9. Roy Lichtenstein
10. ?
11. Pablo Picasso
12. (Uomo Vitruviano by Leonardo Da Vinci)

PS: Is this the right stack exchange site for this subject? I couldn't find an art site

[image: picture of the arty t-shirt]

Comment: I would put Joan Miro between Roy Lietchenstein and Pablo Picasso (lower right arm), the "bug" out of a few lines is very telling and the basic colours fit well.

Comment: rightmost leg: maybe Andreas Englund? Although I don't know if he's a 20th century artist of high enough fame

Comment: Right leg Mondrian

Comment: Inner right leg is mondrian, I meant the outer one

Comment: if you don't mind could you please share where you bought this T-shirt from? My boyfriend has this exact T-shirt but he's worn it to death so I'd love to buy him a nice new one as a surprise!! I've been looking everywhere!

Comment: @sophie, you might want to start with [TypographiaBarcelona](https://www.picuki.com/tag/TypographiaBarcelona)

Comment: I think it was somewhere in Madrid, but I don't remember the name of shop. It's already 5 years ago

Answer (score 11, accepted):

|  | Artist | Section | Work |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | **Magritte** | (Bowler hat) | [*The Son of Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Son_of_Man) |
| [image] | **Magritte** | (Pipe) | [*The Treachery of Images*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images) |
| [image] | **Dalí** | (Arm) | [*Soft Construction with Boiled Beans (Premonition of Civil War)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_Construction_with_Boiled_Beans_(Premonition_of_Civil_War)) |
| [image] | **Dalí** | (Clock) | [*The Persistence of Memory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Persistence_of_Memory) |
| [image] | **Miró** | (Arm) | [*Composition (Petit univers)*](https://www.artsy.net/artwork/joan-miro-composition-petit-univers-composition-small-universe) etc |
| [image] | **Miró** | (Spider, star) | [*Ciphers and Constellations, in Love with a Woman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphers_and_Constellations,_in_Love_with_a_Woman) etc |
| [image] | **Munch** | (Face) | [*The Scream*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scream) |
| [image] | **Kandinsky** | (Arm) | [*In Blue*](https://www.wikiart.org/en/wassily-kandinsky/in-blue-1925) |
| [image] | **Pollock** | (T-shirt) | [*Mural on Indian Red Ground*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mural_on_Indian_Red_Ground) etc |
| [image] | **van Gogh** | (Leg) | [*The Siesta*](http://www.musee-orsay.fr/en/collections/works-in-focus/search/commentaire/commentaire_id/la-meridienne-7100.html) |
| [image] | **Mondrian** | (Leg) | [*Composition A*](https://www.wikiart.org/en/piet-mondrian/composition-a-1923) etc |
| [image] | **Klimt** | (Leg) | [*The Kiss*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kiss_(Klimt)) etc |
| [image] | **Lichtenstein** | (Leg) | [*Garbage Can*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Lichtenstein) etc |
| [image] | **Picasso** | (Arm) | [*Guernica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guernica_(Picasso)) |
| [image] | **da Vinci** | (Body/Circle/Square) | [*Vitruvian Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitruvian_Man) |

Answer (score 2):

Number 6. Is Van Gogh i believe, it looks like the leg from Siesta. See https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Noon,_rest_from_work_-_Van_Gogh.jpeg

Number 10. is Joan Miro. This was a little tougher, I am having trouble locating the image I think this is based on but see Metamorfosi - Joan Miro, 1936, but the hands are very similar and also the colors are very typical of Miro.

Comment: I find myself in agreement with Miro, but not Van Gogh.

Comment: yeah the leg is a real tough one to identify,  especially since i am not sure if van gogh would be considered in the same era as the other painters.  but look at the lines and bends in the knee, toes, and ankle, they are nearly identical to the leg in Siesta.  Also the hatching is pretty darn similar.  Though if anyone has a better match i would love to hear it!